# Create OneDrive folder wp8.1

Tags: onedrive

I have not found in the reference a method to, using the OneDrive SDK on WP8.1, to create a new OneDrive folder.  I am using looking for a method for backing up and syncing across devices and platforms.

Comment: Have you looked through http://dev.onedrive.com? It should have pointers to the information you require - perhaps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn659741.aspx?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a folder in OneDrive using REST: http://onedrive.github.io/items/create.htm 
It shows how to create both a file or a folder in OneDrive.